# How can I constrain a function to not accept partially applied functions

Tags: f#, type-constraints, partial-application

I have a serialization function that I feed data into, some times I miss an argument to the data generating function, and as a result I serialize the partially applied function. Json.Net does not throw up about this, but provides a nice empty object `{}`

I would like to constraint my serialization function to not accept partially applied arguments:

```
let mySerializer<'a when : 'a isnotafunction> (data:'a) : string = 
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
```

So far I have had no luck in finding a way of doing this.

Comment: You can check if `'a` is an instantiation of `FSharpFunc<_,_>`

Comment: how would I go about making this into a constraint? Ie `'a when : 'a not :> FSharpFunc<_,_>`

Comment: Related answer: [how would I constrain to non-function?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35463535/742594)